# Cannot upgrade Laravel 6.x to 7x

Tags: laravel, laravel-ui

Current packages:

"laravel/framework": "^6.2",
"laravel/ui": "^1.2",

I has followed the upgrade guide.
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#updating-dependencies

When I run composer update:

```
Problem:
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.0
    - laravel/ui v1.2.0 requires illuminate/support ~5.8|^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.18.35, 5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev],
```

If I composer require laravel/ui "2.0" I got error that require Laravel 7.

```
Problem:
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v6.18.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.35
    - laravel/ui 2.x-dev requires illuminate/support ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[7.x-dev],
```

Can someone help me with issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure it's work for you or not. Please run this command

`composer require laravel/ui "1.2.0"`

then update your the Laravel

Comment: could you install laravel/ui 1.1.2 ?

Comment: Please check this version  `composer require laravel/ui "1.2.0"`

Comment: Yes..only v1.2. laravel/ui v2 require Laravel 7. I'm stuck in between. If I upgrade Laravel 7 it require ui v2. If I install ui v2 it require Laravel 7.

Comment: No, v1.2 need `illuminate/console: ~5.8|^6.0` 
`illuminate/filesystem: ~5.8|^6.0` 
`illuminate/support: ~5.8|^6.0` . You can check here https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/ui#v1.2.0 please clear composer cache and check again `composer clearcache`

Comment: I have installed laravel/ui v1.2 and it works fine with Laravel 6.x. The problem is I can't upgrade to Laravel 7.x. When I composer update I got error as above. "don't install laravel/framework v7.0.0"

Comment: After install `Laravel UI 1.2.0` please check again and try to update laravel 7.0.

Comment: I did but it doesn't work `Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.0
    - laravel/ui v1.2.0 requires illuminate/support ~5.8|^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.18.35, 5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev],`

Comment: what is version of your `illuminate/support` package  ?

Comment: It solved. I can upgrade to Laravel 7.25.0. Dries Vints helped me identify incompatible third-party packages "jenssegers/date". After upgrade to "jenssegers/date": "^4.0". Everything working fine. Thank you @TirdadAbbasi for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when updating Laravel from 6.* to 7.*, and as Imran said, i just updated

`"jenssegers/date": "^4.0"`

And now works, thanks a lot